# Galois Group of $x^4 - x^2 - 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Find the Galois Group of $x^4 - x^2 - 3$

This is a qual question. I don't know how to find the splitting field of this polynomial.

Comment: **Hint:** the roots of the polynomial are the square roots of the roots of $y^2-y-3$.

Comment: See, Andrew: you could have put that comment to Zev at the end of the question, and save Zev the trouble of telling you what you already knew. That would be so much better than filler text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering $f(x) = x^4 - x^2 - 3 $ we must finds its roots. Well if you take $y = x^2$ it comes that

$$0=y^2 - y - 3  = \left(y - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{4} - 3 = \left(y - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{13}{4} \implies y = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt {13}}{2} $$

and from $x^2 = y$ you find all $4$ roots of $f$.

Comment: I just realized this is exactly what I tried to do but messed up the computation. Appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to see from this that the splitting field is a degree eight extension of the rationals. Given that the Galois group is a subgroup of $S_4$, we can then deduce that ...